# Read model value and disable certain textbox when page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I wanna to ask how can I achieve disable textbox by condition. Example, When dropdown list selected "Card". Commission text field will be appear. If model value is "Cash" the Commission text field will be hide.

```
<div class="k-edit-field">
   @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.PAY_TYPE)
   .DataTextField("NAME")
   .DataValueField("CODE")
   .DataSource(source =>
   {
     source.Read(read =>
     {
      read.Action("GetPayType", "Payment");
     });
   })
  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%", @id = "payType"})
  )
 </div>

<div class="k-edit-field" id="ASD">
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PAY_COMM)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PAY_COMM)
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#payType").on("change", function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "C") {
            $('#Comm').show();
        } else {
            $('#Comm').hide();
        }
    });

    $("#payType").trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: Use js is right,what you want to change,without js?

Comment: @YiyiYou , actually I want make it, when the page load is done. The field will auto hide / appear, if the model value is not "C" or it is. As now it only trigger when I select the dropdown value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the value when page load and when dropdown change.

```
function changeComm() {
            if ($("#payType").val() == "C") {
                $('#Comm').show();
            } else {
                $('#Comm').hide();
            }
        }
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            changeComm();
            $("#payType").on("change", function () {
                changeComm();
            });

            $("#payType").trigger("change");
        });
```